# Is there a better way to short-circuit a chain of instanceof?

Tags: java, oop, switch-statement, instanceof

My class originally began with several separate `addAListener()` `addBListener()` and `removeAListener`, etc. This wasn't so bad with one class but it really explodes outwards when the class gets used internally by another class and extended listeners get propagated out.

A simple solution is to use a single interface and sort out the listener with an `instanceof`:

```
public interface Listener {
}

public class ListenerA extends Listener {
}

public class ListenerB extends Listener {
}

public class ListenerC extends Listener {
}

List<ListenerA> ofListenersA = new List<>();
List<ListenerB> ofListenersB = new List<>();
List<ListenerC> ofListenersC = new List<>();

void addListener(Listener listener) {
    if (listener instanceof ListenerA) {
        ofListenersA.add(listener);

        return;
    }

    if (listener instanceof ListenerB) {
        ofListenersB.add(listener);

        return;
    }

    if (listener instanceof ListenerB) {
        ofListenersB.add(listener);

        return;
    }
}

void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    if (listener instanceof ListenerA) {
        ofListenersA.remove(listener);

        return;
    }

    if (listener instanceof ListenerB) {
        ofListenersB.remove(listener);

        return;
    }

    if (listener instanceof ListenerB) {
        ofListenersB.remove(listener);

        return;
    }
}
```

But now I have to evaluate each `instanceof` exclusively as you can't `switch` on a class.

This is not an attempt to ask for an optimization as I don't have many kinds of listeners to check for; but rather a question on whether this is a bad approach when it comes to object-oriented design.

**Update**

Short-circuit approach using enum within the interface:

```
enum ListenerType {
    ListenerTypeA,
    ListenerTypeB,
    ListenerTypeC
}

public interface Listener {
    ListenerType getType();
}

public class ListenerA extends Listener {
    ListenerType getType() {
        return ListenerType.ListenerTypeA;
    }
}

public class ListenerB extends Listener {
    ListenerType getType() {
        return ListenerType.ListenerTypeB;
    }
}

public class ListenerC extends Listener {
    ListenerType getType() {
        return ListenerType.ListenerTypeC;
    }
}

List<ListenerA> ofListenersA = new List<>();
List<ListenerB> ofListenersB = new List<>();
List<ListenerC> ofListenersC = new List<>();

void addListener(Listener listener) {
    switch (listener) {
        case ListenerTypeA: {
            ofListenersA.add(listener);

            return;
        }
        case ListenerTypeB: {
            ofListenersB.add(listener);

            return;
        }
        case ListenerTypeC: {
            ofListenersC.add(listener);

            return;
        }
    }
}

void removeListener(Listener listener) {
    switch (listener) {
        case ListenerTypeA: {
            ofListenersA.remove(listener);

            return;
        }
        case ListenerTypeB: {
            ofListenersB.remove(listener);

            return;
        }
        case ListenerTypeC: {
            ofListenersC.remove(listener);

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using `instanceof`, then your design is probably wrong. Why do you want to keep track of all of these listeners separately, and if you need them separate, why a single `addListener` method?

Comment: Because I have other objects which use objects of this class as private members. So when I want to provide listeners from above I have to reimplement each add/remove listener again for that class. The reason I have them all as separate listeners is because I loop over each of them individually for different events.

Comment: I have viewed many opensource project but I could not remember any of them who uses single method for generic listeners, often: you would want to create a method for each listener and add some intuitive names.

Comment: @Zhro A `class` can't extend an `interface` . #justsaying.

Comment: @Zhro, you can have a interface and in its abstract method you can have a variable defining the event type (variable can be of type enum). Now single interface and single method. You also need single array of listeners. Other way is single interface with various methods in it based on event types. Just take care you do not end up having Fat interfaces. Butt anyways too much scattered code is also not good. Refer my answer below. Hope it will be hepful

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you add a type to specify which type of listener you're interested in. You can also change the key to something else, for example a regular class with hashCode and equals.

```
enum ListenerType {
    TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C
}

interface Listener {

}

Map<ListenerType, Set<Listener>> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public void addListener(ListenerType type, Listener listener) {
    listeners.computeIfAbsent(type, k -> Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>())).add(listener);
}

public void removeListener(ListenerType type, Listener listener) {
    listeners.computeIfPresent(type, (k, v) -> v.remove(listener) && v.isEmpty() ? null : v);
}

public Set<Listener> getListeners(ListenerType type) {
    return listeners.getOrDefault(type, Collections.emptySet());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a single `interface` and define an `enum`. In the `abstract method` of the `interface` you can have the instance of `enum` as parameter.

*Now you need only one list of listeners.*

Now you can invoke method as per the action or event type. While implementing you can process as per the `enum instance type`.

Other way is to have a `single interface` with `different methods`. Call the method as per the event occuring and while implementing you can process as per the method.

Advantage of method of single method with a variable defining the event type (variable of type enum, string or integer but prefer enum) is that if in case more actions are added you just need not add those in the interface and not much change will be needed. You just need to add added action in the enum (if you have string or integer constants, then accordingly you may define extra constant for new action). Now you can call the same method with a newly defined action type.

Just need to take care to avoid `Fat` interfaces. You need to balance between too thin(single interface per method) vs fat interface. You can group the methods belonging to a logical same task in an interface. Too scattered code is also bad and putting every (related and unrelated ) apis in an single interface is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

There is (in my experience) always a better way than to use `instanceOf` without knowing your codebase it is hard to say what is most appropriate, but depending on the situation the following are good for type comparison:

- Maps, they can operate in much the same way as a type based switch statement, as long as you make the key of the map the type you wish to switch on then its just up to you what gets returned when it matches.
- [Command Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command), where you substitute your listener class hierarchy as the abstract/concrete commands. Then you can encapsulate the actual behaviour into the receivers.
- [Visitor Pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm), if you want to notify all listeners at once then the visitor pattern might be applicable, the type comparison is done again through your listener hierarchy as the elements that get visited.

I hope this is of some use let me know if i'm off base.

Answer (score 0):

We have used Visitor pattern in such scenarios. 
It is also easy to maintain the code with visitor pattern in case when new implementation for Listener are added.